# Scripts for /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ to handle resolvconf -u

Tags: linux, networkmanager, resolv.conf

There are two ways for `networkmanager`:

- update `/etc/resolv.conf`
- do not update `/etc/resolv.conf` at all

Both solutions are not suitable at my side as at my side I need `/etc/resolv.conf` to be handled by `resolvconf`, such that it can be regenerated any time with `resolvconf -u`.

What I would need are scripts for `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` which correctly work together with `resolvconf`.

However I was not able to find suitable scripts for what I think it is a pretty basic standard case.

So is there any standard solution for that (please provide essential part of the scripts here) or does everybody really need to re-invent the wheel each time?

Notes:

There apparently is something, but this seems not to work correctly.

In my case I have `dnsmasq`, VPN and more, all fiddling with the DNS.

However `resolvconf -u` does not regenerate `/etc/resolv.conf` correctly, so the default setting apparently lacks something.

To be more elaborate:

- `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown` calls `run-parts /etc/network/if-up.d`
- `/etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf` then examines `$IF_DNS_NAMESERVER` and `$IF_DNS_NAMESERVERS` but `networkmanager` does not provide those and sets `IP4_NAMESERVERS` instead (according to manual)

Hence there somewhere is a missing link.  Here is a copy of what is found in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Script to dispatch NetworkManager events
#
# Runs ifupdown scripts when NetworkManager fiddles with interfaces.
# See NetworkManager(8) for further documentation of the dispatcher events.

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "$0: called with no interface" 1>&2
    exit 1;
fi

# Fake ifupdown environment
export IFACE="$1"
export LOGICAL="$1"
export ADDRFAM="NetworkManager"
export METHOD="NetworkManager"
export VERBOSITY="0"

# Run the right scripts
case "$2" in
    up|vpn-up)
    export MODE="start"
    export PHASE="post-up"
    exec run-parts /etc/network/if-up.d
    ;;
    down|vpn-down)
    export MODE="stop"
    export PHASE="post-down"
    exec run-parts /etc/network/if-post-down.d
    ;;
# pre-up/pre-down not implemented. See
# https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=387832
#    pre-up)
#   export MODE="start"
#   export PHASE="pre-up"
#   exec run-parts /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
#   ;;
#    pre-down)
#   export MODE="stop"
#   export PHASE="pre-down"
#   exec run-parts /etc/network/if-down.d
#   ;;
    hostname|dhcp4-change|dhcp6-change)
        # Do nothing
    ;;
    *)
    echo "$0: called with unknown action \`$2'" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Here is what is found in `/etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf`

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ifup hook script for resolvconf
#
# This file is part of the resolvconf package.
#

[ -x /sbin/resolvconf ] || exit 0

case "$ADDRFAM" in
  inet|inet6) : ;;
  *) exit 0 ;;
esac

R=""
if [ "$IF_DNS_DOMAIN" ] ; then
    R="${R}domain $IF_DNS_DOMAIN
"
fi
if [ "$IF_DNS_SEARCH" ] ; then
    R="${R}search $IF_DNS_SEARCH
"
fi
if [ "$IF_DNS_SORTLIST" ] ; then
    R="${R}sortlist $IF_DNS_SORTLIST
"
fi
for NS in $IF_DNS_NAMESERVER $IF_DNS_NAMESERVERS ; do
    R="${R}nameserver $NS
"
done

echo -n "$R" | /sbin/resolvconf -a "${IFACE}.${ADDRFAM}" || :
```

FYI it is from Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Looks like this problem is specific to me.  I will add an answer when I find a solution to this, including a root cause analysis where the problem comes from.  However, I do not know how long it takes until I find the time to do so, as I already have a workaround in place (which was a fast, far from correct, but working solution).

Answer (score 0):

Scripts? NetworkManager has had native /bin/resolvconf support since 2008 ([version 0.7.0](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/?id=0760152f9f49f2d7014673aad19712a65e56281b)). Your distribution needs to enable it at compile time using `./configure --with-resolvconf=…` ([e.g.](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/networkmanager&id=272293f3aea37c24227ab3bf980849383d21c006#n46)). There is no need for separate dispatcher.d scripts here – you just have some as a side effect of your distro trying to integrate NM with ifupdown.

If it doesn't work for you, check whether your `NetworkManager.conf` manual page mentions `dns` and `rc-manager` settings (they vary between versions). Normally resolvconf works by default, but it could be that you need to manually set `dns=default` or `rc-manager=resolvconf` or both.

Comment: I mean `/etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf` uses those variables which comes with `resolvconf`

Comment: No, it doesn't. That's an ifupdown script, not a NetworkManager script, and it expects variables that ifupdown would export. But since Debian wants to run ifupdown scripts from NM, it is up to `dispatcher.d/01ifupdown` to correctly translate the environment from NM variables to ifupdown variables.

Comment: apparently there is no such translation.  I will add the script to my question above.

Comment: Then maybe your best option is to disable/remove `if-up.d/000resolvconf` and use NM's built-in resolvconf support? I see Debian does enable it at build time, not sure about other distros.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35813/discussion-between-tino-and-grawity).